# Showing root directory twice at URL

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to redirect from one page to next page. Here, After all the processing it redirects/submits to the next page with a hiddenForm submission so that these values can be available at next page.

HTML Part : (Homepage.html)

```html
----------------------
----------------------
<form id="hiddenForm">
    <input id="userId" name="userId" type="hidden" value="">
    <input id="password" name="password" type="hidden" value="">
    <input id="type" name="type" type="hidden" value="">
</form>
----------------------
----------------------
```

JS part :

```
function getReports(){           
    document.getElementById('hiddenForm').setAttribute("action","./Report.html");
    document.getElementById('hiddenForm').submit();
}

function getTasks(){           
    document.getElementById('hiddenForm').setAttribute("action","./Task.html");
    document.getElementById('hiddenForm').submit();
}
```

it creates following problems:

Case 1. if I use `--------- .setAttribute("action","./Report.html");`

Then it works fine, all the pages are traversed well but in URL, it's repeating the values twice.

like :

```
 http://localhost:8085/MyApp/Report.html?password=admin&userId=4&type=ADMIN#/Report.html?password=admin&userId=4&type=ADMIN
```

Case 2. if I use `--------- .setAttribute("action","MyApp/Report.html");`

Then it shows the value at URL once well but the root directory is repeated twice.

like :

```
 http://localhost:8085/MyApp/MyApp/Report.html?password=admin&userId=4&type=ADMIN
```

that results "Object Not Found" Error.

So, I am not getting why Case 1 repeats the value twice at url ? And Why Case 2 repeats the root directory itself ?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing that you showed here would cause this, so it must be something you aren't showing.

Comment: So your current location is the same folder as where the report.html file is, yet you try to either use ./ to refer to this folder (you could just leave ./ off) and then you try to refer to the root WITHOUT referring to the root (MyApp is a folder in your current location, not a folder in your root, that would be /MyApp). So first try without the ./, then try with prepending a /. Why the first one duplicates, I don't know, but I do see why the second one duplicates since you are already in your myApp folder, presumably.

Comment: @ somethinghere... I tried with both as you suggested. without ./ is just like the Case 1 (repeating the values twice at URL) and if prepending / then it's giving error as "Object not found". So, still it's not working. Any further suggestion ?